# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle' in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-cycle

So I have a website that is done in PHP. I have to include a simple slider in the website with this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wb3se/

```
$('#slides').cycle({ 
    fx: 'scrollLeft'
});
```

Very very simple code. Im getting that error which from what I understand usually means that the browser does not understand what 'cycle' mean. I am using jquery 1.10. So no idea why it would do that. Here is how it is setup.

Header.php has a link to jQuery on googles server, and has a link to a hard copy of cycle.js on the server.

The body has the html in it, css file has css in it

footer has the java.js file with the javascript in it followed by `</body>` tag.

Comment: check your browsers network tab to see whether the cycle plugin file is downloaded properly

Comment: I am using chrome and I am not getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the cycle plugin isn't loaded when you're initializing the slideshow. Check the NET tab in firebug or the resources tab in Chrome developer tools. Make sure the link to cycle is before your slideshow code. Also, make sure the DOM is ready when you initialize cycle:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slides').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollLeft'
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slides').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollLeft'
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. The plugin was loading before the script was firing off but it seemed to work when I wrapped it in a function. For some reason it wasnt giving me problems in the HTML version of the site but It was giving me problems in the PHP. Still not sure why, but I guess all is well now. Thanks